# What is the normal workflow when parsing multiple files with multiple Grunt tasks

Tags: gruntjs

By workflow I mean, if a task creates multiple files (e.g. `copy`), then another tasks compresses all those files into one (e.g. `uglify`), how do I get rid of the files created by copy which I don't need anymore?

Right now, I'm copying files in a temp folders, uglifying them into a single file outside the temp folder, then removing the temp folder using `clean`.

Is that the proper way of doing this, or can it be done better?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Bixi. [extra chars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the scale of the project and the number of files one has to maintain. On projects that do generate a lot of files dynamically like `jekyll`- and `haml`-based projects, it's sane to use the workflow you mentioned.

It would also make sense in very complex, `javascript`-heavy projects.

But note that the `copy` and `clean` tasks are mainly there to keep stuff organized and stashed in their rightful places. Organization has a lot to do with what order one runs tasks, what kind of files one has to maintain, how separated they are (and are expected to remain), how they are expected to be loaded, if they are meant for production, etc.

In most of my projects I use only `compass` for `CSS`, `uglify`, `jshint` and `jasmine` for `javascript` and a couple of other tasks like `watch` and `connect` to keep the flow smooth. In that workflow `copy`, `clean` and `concat` would be overkill. My 2¢!

Comment: Aha, OK. Thanks, Wallace.